# Having trouble with Javafx ListView

Tags: javafx

I encountered a wield problem when I'm working on a ListView with customed cells.

The code is something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();

        BorderPane b1 = new BorderPane();
        b1.setPrefHeight(25);
        VBox.setVgrow(b1, Priority.NEVER);
        b1.setLeft(new Label("Title"));

        ListView<Item> traceSetList = new ListView<>();
        VBox.setVgrow(traceSetList, Priority.ALWAYS);
        traceSetList.setCellFactory(listView -> {
            ListCell<Item> listCell = new ListCell<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getName());
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                        cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(item.getSelectedProperty());
                        setGraphic(cb);
                    }
                }
            };
            return listCell;
        });
        traceSetList.getItems().addAll(addItems());

        HBox h1 = new HBox();
        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Label"), new Spinner<Integer>());
        VBox.setVgrow(h1, Priority.NEVER);

        root.getChildren().addAll(b1, traceSetList, h1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static List<Item> addItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add(new Item("item-" + i));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Data
    public static class Item {
        private String name;
        private final SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

The code above is just a simplified sample, so no problem at all. My application is a little more complicated, and I'm not sure what causing the problem.

Here is the problem:

[image]

From the pic above, you can see that there is more space at the bottom of the ListView, but it won't display the rest items.

And when I try to scroll the ListView by draging the ScrollBar or rolling the mouse, it wouldn't work properly. When I try to scroll to the bottom, the blank space moved to the top, and I cannot see the last item:

[image]

The behaviour looks like the ListView cannot get the cell size correct, so that it cannot layout properly. Or maybe there are some empty items. I'm not sure what the problem is, and where to look at. Really need some suggestions.

I cannot reproduce the problem by the sample code. Sorry for that.

Comment: @jewelsea You are right. I was using 17.0.8. Tried 21.0.1 just now, and the problem is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were errors in the JavaFX ListView scrolling behavior with custom cells in some JavaFX versions (I don't recall exact versions, but something like 17-20) and numerous bugs were fixed (some may remain).

Try the most recent stable version (JavaFX 21.0.1).

As noted by the asker in comments:

> I was using 17.0.8. Tried 21.0.1 just now, and the problem is gone.